# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 7 supplied.?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py, pycord

my error:
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 7 supplied.?

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT player, invites FROM join WHERE server = {member.guild.id} AND spieler = {member.id}")
invites = cursor.fetchone() 

cursor.execute(f"SELECT leaves FROM invite_ge WHERE spieler = {invites[0]} AND invite = ?", (invites [1]))
```

Comment: `(invites [1])` should be `(invites [1],)` You need the comma to make it a tuple.

Comment: Why are you using string formatting for any of the substitutions? You should use `cursor.execute` parameters for all substitutions.